# I can't fix "BuildPlayerWindow+BuildMethodException: 3 errors"

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, build

I'm newbie to making my own games. months ago I created my first project. Once the build is complete, it builds normally.
But now, suddenly I can't build again because of this error
**v
v
v**

1

```
Internal build system error. BuildProgram exited with code -2146233088.
System.Exception: Failed to resolve target API for values
   at AndroidPlayerBuildProgram.AndroidPlayerBuildProgram.GetPathTargetAPI(NPath path)
   at AndroidPlayerBuildProgram.AndroidPlayerBuildProgram.EnumerateAPILevelResources(NPath srcAPKResources, NPath dstAPKResources, String resourceName)+MoveNext()
   at AndroidPlayerBuildProgram.AndroidPlayerBuildProgram.CopyIdsXML(NPath srcAPKResources)+MoveNext()
   at AndroidPlayerBuildProgram.AndroidPlayerBuildProgram.SetupGradleResources()+MoveNext()
   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1.InsertRange(Int32 index, IEnumerable`1 collection)
   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1.AddRange(IEnumerable`1 collection)
   at AndroidPlayerBuildProgram.AndroidPlayerBuildProgram.SetupPlayerBuild()
   at PlayerBuildProgramLibrary.PlayerBuildProgramBase.RunBuildProgram()
   at PlayerBuildProgramTypeWrapper.Run(String[] args)
   at Program.Main(String[] args)
UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent (int,intptr,bool&)
```

2

```
BuildFailedException: Incremental Player build failed!
UnityEditor.Modules.BeeBuildPostprocessor.PostProcess (UnityEditor.Modules.BuildPostProcessArgs args) (at <0d6ce211ebbc47e1a35a84c3672ff58f>:0)
UnityEditor.Modules.DefaultBuildPostprocessor.PostProcess (UnityEditor.Modules.BuildPostProcessArgs args, UnityEditor.BuildProperties& outProperties) (at <0d6ce211ebbc47e1a35a84c3672ff58f>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.AndroidBuildPostprocessor.PostProcess (UnityEditor.Modules.BuildPostProcessArgs args, UnityEditor.BuildProperties& outProperties) (at <5160fdea082d4c479eac116da4ffc2de>:0)
UnityEditor.PostprocessBuildPlayer.Postprocess (UnityEditor.BuildTargetGroup targetGroup, UnityEditor.BuildTarget target, System.Int32 subtarget, System.String installPath, System.String companyName, System.String productName, System.Int32 width, System.Int32 height, UnityEditor.BuildOptions options, UnityEditor.RuntimeClassRegistry usedClassRegistry, UnityEditor.Build.Reporting.BuildReport report) (at <0d6ce211ebbc47e1a35a84c3672ff58f>:0)
UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr, Boolean&)
```

3

```
Build completed with a result of 'Failed' in 41 seconds (40802 ms)
UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent (int,intptr,bool&)
```

and this

```
UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow+BuildMethodException: 3 errors
  at UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow+DefaultBuildMethods.BuildPlayer (UnityEditor.BuildPlayerOptions options) [0x002da] in <0d6ce211ebbc47e1a35a84c3672ff58f>:0 
  at UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow.CallBuildMethods (System.Boolean askForBuildLocation, UnityEditor.BuildOptions defaultBuildOptions) [0x00080] in <0d6ce211ebbc47e1a35a84c3672ff58f>:0 
UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent (int,intptr,bool&)
```

*I've been looking for people with the same problem as me. I tried to follow But I can't solve this problem*

I did before :

- `After I encountered a problem I have tried deleting and reinstalling Unity.`
- `I have tried creating a new project. and copy some of the models.`
- `I created an empty projectใ`
- `I tried installing another unity version.`

But there is no way to solve this problem...

Comment: Just fyi, actually the only error relevant is the first one ... the others are just follow up errors bubbling through the build pipeline and are just telling you **that** the build failed. The very first one is the one telling you the **why**

Comment: Maybe the according SDK/NDK for the selected target API level is not installed on your system?

Comment: I have all installed. ready for build

Comment: Maybe I should go check it out again